# what is the function of (だと) and (一人) in this sentence

Tags: meaning

the sentence is "もう駄目だと　一人孤独を抱いても".

i took this sentence from this page:

"http://honyakusitemita.pixnet.net/blog/post/91368550-%5Bblood%2B%EF%BC%88%E8%A1%80%E6%88%B0%EF%BC%89-%E7%89%87%E9%A0%AD%E6%9B%B23%5Duverworld-color-of-the-heart",
it is a song of uverworld.

i have understood that this sentences means someting like:

"even if it useless, i embrace the solitude", but i don't know what means exactly.

then, i also don't know what is the function of this(だと), and this (ひとり) in te sentence.

thanks in advance, guys.

Comment: もう駄目だ**といいながら**、一人孤独を抱いても？

Comment: the sentence is written as you see it :"もう駄目だと　一人孤独を抱いても" . the sentence is part of a song; the lyrics of the song are in the link of the post.

Comment: とcan be と言います if it's end of a sentence.

Comment: it could be, but in the sentence (the original sentence in the lyrics of the song), the (と) is between (もう駄目だ) and (一人) . i've thought two things about this: 1. the (と) is goes with (だ) ,and as a result, we have=(だと) that means something like:when or if is. then, the sentence must mean something like: even if is usseles...

Comment: 2. the (と) designates a quote, but i have troubles with this; because in the original lyrics, (駄目うもだ) isn't in  parentheses (「」this things), and afther the ( と) there is nothing like (といいながら) , or (と思います) that complements the (と).